# How do I access Bobbi's Terminal (Console?)

Tags: fallout-4, ps4, xbox-one

In Bobbi's Place located in Good Neighbor, Bobbi's Safe is accessible only through Bobbi's Terminal (on desk next to safe.) The terminal is unable to be accessed due to a bug. The PC has a current workaround however I am unable to find a solution for console, specifically the Xbox One. Please help.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot access the terminal. I know this isn't exactly what you wanted to hear, sorry. Like you said, there is a workaround for PC, but there are no alternatives for consoles. The bug has not been fixed.

Comment: You're right, not the answer I wanted. However it is an answer and for that I am very grateful. At least I can move on. It is a shame Bethesda Game Studios appear to have moved on from Fallout 4's bugs but from what I read from screenshots for PC the safe items are not special or unique so I can brush it off w/o anymore fuss. Principle? Sure. But as the sad maxim of truth goes "it is what it is." Again I express gratitude Aulis my friend, THANK YOU!

Comment: @Wrigglenite, I did not read your "edit" yet I also thank you for what appears to be some sort of implied "edit." We are a team of gamers and your experience on Arquade should be noted. Aulis and I appear to be "younger" here. I'm grateful to both yourself for guidance and (of course) Aulis for his (so quickly replied) Answer. 